# Convert `list` to `data.frame` without losing the names

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Here is a list

```
l1 = list(apple=c(2,23,43), pear = c(4,5), pineapple= 2, banana=97)
```

and here is the `data.frame` I am trying to construct from this list.

```
data.frame(fruit = c("apple","apple","apple","pear","pear","pineapple", "banana"), number = c(2,23,43,4,5,2,97))
      fruit number
1     apple      2
2     apple     23
3     apple     43
4      pear      4
5      pear      5
6 pineapple      2
7    banana     97
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `melt`

```
library(reshape2)
setNames(melt(l1), c('number', 'fruit'))
```

or a `base R` option is `stack`

```
stack(l1)
```